# Gnome top bar has no on-line accounts icon(Gnome-ubuntu-14.04)

Tags: gnome, 14.04, empathy, online-accounts

This might be unsolvable but:
after the update (to 14.04 from 13.10) the status icon for empathy/on-line accounts vanished, now I dint know if I am connected to Facebook, gmail and other Nsa associations. is there a way to put it back in or replace it?